# String issue in Swift

Tags: xcode, string, format, swift, nsurl

I keep getting an error when I try to pass a string to NSURL. A regular string without format works fine but the code below keeps giving me the following error: "could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments"
Any advice appreciated thanks.

```
var str = (format: "%@send?x=%d&y=%d2&z=%d", URL, x, y, z)
var url = NSURL(String: str)
```

or

```
var url = NSURL(format: "%@send?x=%d&y=%d2&z=%d", URL, x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `String` type name in your string initializer:

```
let URL = "http://example.com/"
let (x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3)
let str = String(format: "%@send?x=%d&y=%d2&z=%d", URL, x, y, z)
// str is now "http://example.com/send?x=1&y=22&z=3"

let url = NSURL(string: str)
```